# couldn't declare solidity version in remix

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I tried initializing solidity version but I get this error, how to di it right way

```
paragma solidity ^0.8.14;
```

error

```
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got '^'
 --> .deps/SimpleStorage.sol:1:18:
  |
1 | paragma solidity ^0.8.14;
  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be `pragma` instead of `paragma`